# Go to inscription page

Tags: java, spring, post, thymeleaf

i'm have problem with load page by id. I'm creating simple forum in Spring and when i created topic i got page like this /topic/10 (10 is id topic) and nextly i want to add inscription to this topic so after click button submit should be /inscription/topic/10 (10 is id topic). Now is the problem, when i click button i got Error 405 but when i take this line and write by hand or copy address and paste it again then i got inscription page. Where is problem? Its can be thymeleaf or spring request?
Code is below

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/inscription/")
public class InscriptionController {

private InscriptionService inscriptionService;

private TopicService topicService;

@Autowired
private InscriptionController(InscriptionService inscriptionService, TopicService topicService) {
    this.inscriptionService = inscriptionService;
    this.topicService = topicService;
}

@GetMapping("topic/{id}")
public String in2(@ModelAttribute("inscription") Inscription inscription, @PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    Topic topic = topicService.findOne(id);
    model.addAttribute("inscription", inscription);
    return "inscription";
}
```

Thymeleaf - here when i press button New Message should be go to inscription/topic/id

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create new topic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #969bd9;">
    <span class="navbar-brand">Create new topic</span>
</nav>

<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md6 col-md-offset-3">

            <form th:action="@{/inscription/topic/{id}(id = ${topic.id})}" th:object="${inscription}" method="post">
            <h5>
                <a th:href="@{/topic/{id}(id = topic.id)}"></a>
                <span th:text="${topic.title}"></span>
            </h5>

            <div class="col s10">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s11">
                        Stworzony
                        <p th:text="${topic.createdAt} ? ${#calendars.format(topic.createdAt, 'HH:mm dd MMMM yyyy')}"></p>
                        <p th:utext="${#strings.replace(topic.text,T(java.lang.System).getProperty('line.separator'),'&lt;br /&gt;')}"></p>
                        <div class="divider"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">New message</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

405 error means "[Method Not Allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)". When you click the `submit` button, your `form` will perform the `POST` method, which doesn't have the corresponding mapping in your controller. You should add `POST` mapping to your controller or change the `form` method to `GET`.